# NMR Chemical shift and the electron distribution

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, fermions, nuclear-magnetic-resonance

We explain the position of a hydrogen environment as being downfield if it is deshielded by its proximity to an electron withdrawing group. The electrons around the nucleus protect said nucleus from surrounding magnetic fields, so it effectively "feels" a weaker magnetic field. My question is what is happening to the electrons to cause the phenomena?